# MySQL: How do I get a piece of information from one table based on it's id in another table

Tags: mysql, database, relational

I have two tables: Suppliers and Unit_User.

The Suppliers table has a field called suppliersunit which contains a comma-separated list of ids. These are the ids of the Units in the Unit_User table.
I need the query to get the unit_name from Unit_User for each of the ids in the suppliersunit column.

I know this is relatively simple but I'm pretty new to MySQL so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: "contains a comma-separated list" about says it all. You need to redesign your table into a properly [normalized](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) layout. Then your problem becomes a simple `JOIN` operation.

Comment: To do what @MarcB is saying, either add a `Suppliers` column to `Unit_User` if it can have only one supplier, or create a `SuppliersUnit_UsersMap` table with rows that have the IDs of both

Answer (score 0):

Comma separated values are bad design. If you can't redesign the table or if you are using someone else's table try using application code to parse and do the query. It would be unreliable to do it through SQL.

Comment: This is not an answer. It should have been a comment.